# Почему вместо русских символов и чисел выводится непонятные символы в таблице?

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <locale.h> 
int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
char name1[7], name2[9], name3[12];
char initials1[5], initials2[5], initials3[5];
unsigned short year1, year2, year3;
float number1, number2, number3;
printf("1. Введите: фамилию, инициалы, год рожд., оклад > ");
scanf("%s %s %hu %f", name1, initials1, &year1, &number1);
printf("\n2. Введите: фамилию, инициалы, год рожд., оклад > ");
scanf("%s %s %hu %f", name2, initials2, &year2, &number2);
printf("\n3. Введите: фамилию, инициалы, год рожд., оклад > ");
scanf("%s %s %hu %f", name3, initials3, &year3, &number3);
printf("\n----------------------------------------------\n");
printf("\n|Отдел кадров                                |\n");
printf("\n----------------------------------------------\n");
printf("\n|Фамилия    |Инициалы     |Год рожд   |Оклад |\n");
printf("\n----------------------------------------------\n");
printf("|%-11s|%-13s|%-10.9hu|%5f|", name1, initials1, &year1, &number1);
printf("\n----------------------------------------------\n");
printf("|%-11s|%-13s|%-10.9hu|%5f|", name2, initials2, &year2, &number2);
printf("\n----------------------------------------------\n");
printf("|%-11s|%-13s|%-10.9hu|%5f|", name3, initials3, &year3, &number3);
  printf("\n----------------------------------------------\n");

}
```

Данные, которые ввожу с клавиатуры и непонятные символы в фото -
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlDMy.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это связано с кодировкой консоли. Перед тем как считать с клавиатуры текст смени кодировку.

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
scanf("%s %s %hu %f", name1, initials1, &year1, &number1);
SetConsoleCP(866);
```

или в начале попробуй поставить

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "utf-8");
```

Что-то из этого должно сработать